# When ISS Launches Cubesats, which direction do they usually fire them?

Tags: iss, cubesat

I was listening to Houston We Have A Podcast and they mentioned that spare payload on ISS supply/crew runs frequently get filled with cubesats which get (more elegantly than the word suggests) tossed out of the station to insert them into orbit.

It occurred to me that if they're tossing these retrograde they're getting free stationkeeping dV? That seems likely to put the cubesat into a more rapidly decaying orbit, but cubesats are cheap. That's the whole point.

So, since they have a mechanism for launching these... which way are they going?

Comment: realted: [Are the cubesats deployed from the ISS always directed “nadir and retrograde”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29531/12102) and  [What are the orbital mechanical consideration behind hand-launched nanosatellites from the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22732/12102) and [Why would the future Nanoracks airlock be built so that it must be removed from the ISS to deploy cubesats?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20144/12102)

Comment: Those questions may be outdated and not duplicates, so I think it might be best to wait and see what an up-to-date answer tells use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer:

Don't know about the general case, but I can answer for one.

Using these two nice pictures of a Nanoracks deploy:

[image]

[image]

I was able to match the Japanese robot arm position in the NASA visualization tool [DOUG](https://vrlab.jsc.nasa.gov/)

[image]

and then we can rotate the view to see the big picture of which way it's pointing.

[image]

So, diagonally nadir & aft.

Picture sources

- [spaceref](http://spaceref.biz/company/nanoracks/nanoracks-update-on-cubesat-deployer-problem.html)
- [Nanoracks](https://nanoracks.com/wp-content/uploads/Nanoracks-Cubesats-e1392227441495.jpg)